# Need Explanation for this C# code in Console Application at Network Files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, network-programming, ip

Can anyone explain me this part of code, because I want build a Console Application (to make a server that connects to the mobile game) with this code in Network files and I want to know the meaning of it.

```
bool Local = false;  // or bool Local = true;
IPAddress[] _Addresses = Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName).AddressList;
IPEndPoint _LocalEP = new IPEndPoint(_Addresses[_Addresses.Length - 1], Constants.ServerPort);
this._Listener = new Socket(_LocalEP.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
this._Listener.ReceiveBufferSize = 2048;
this._Listener.SendBufferSize = 2048;
if (Local)

{
   this._Listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), Constants.ServerPort));
}
else
{
   if (_LocalEP.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
   {
       this._Listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, false);
       this._Listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, _LocalEP.Port));
   }
   else
   {
       this._Listener.Bind(_LocalEP);
   }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get unreachable code, because you variable `Local` is never assigned and will always be `false` by default. Meaning the true branch of the `if (Local)` will never be reached.

So making it true/false will not change it since it is always a constant and includes one of the branches and excludes another.

If you are planning to use it as debug (setting true/false manually in editor), you can either ignore it or write all lines without `if` and comment them instead. If it's production code, then there is something wrong with your logic and 'Local' variable must be updated somehow.

Comment: Thank you, for the suggestion.
But now I have changed the question, SO can you please re-answer for the new question.

Comment: You have not really changed anything in your code itself. You did `= false`, but this is default in any case. So it's still constant. As to the explanation of the network stuff itself, I can't help you too much here unfortunately. I suggest that you ask a separate question about the networking details

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting the value of `bool Local`, when you use it in the `if` it will have the default value of `false`, always.